# Implementing a refreshing table with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable

I'm doing a Swing application where in one of its forms, I have a table which I want to update periodically. I first thought of using a `Timer`, but the task may be time consuming and it may freeze the GUI. Then, I thought of using a `SwingWorker`, but it is designed to be executed once, and I need to execute this task periodically (every two or three minutes) while the form is open.

In this form's code I have implemented three methods: `acceptNew()`, which runs a quick UPDATE query, `listRequests()`, which runs some queries to fill an `ArrayList` with all the records; and `manipulateTable()`, which compares the table model with the ArrayList and updates/inserts the records.

In short, `acceptNew()` does a quick task, `listRequests()` does another task which its completion time depends of the number of records in the DB, and `manipulateTable()` updates the GUI. I need to call these three methods periodically without freezing the GUI.

Comment: 1. please whats, where and why is there the difference between to call `myTimer -> myVoid` and `mySwingWorker -> myVoid`, 2. shortly all updates shoud be done in `XxxTableModel` and `myModel.add/insert/updateRow` should be wrapped inside `invokeLater`,  3. votingto close as too broad (tons post about with OPs effort - code in SSCCE/MCVE form)

Comment: you can archive this one using Multithreading, But u must careful about execution orders use Synchronized Blocks..[example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SwingWorker's `publish` to emit the new state of `listRequests()` that you call `manipulateTable()` in the `process` method and sleep inbetween.

Or just create and submit a new SwingWorker that updates it once every time from a Timer.

Comment: Thank you, **ratchet freak**! I used the second approach and worked like a charm! Cheers!